# Image display for few seconds in YouTube video

Tags: android, youtube-api

In my application, we are capturing a video and uploading it to YouTube. But the requirement is, we need to display one image for 2 seconds before the video and after the video (similar to ads in Youtube videos)

And also we need to display a logo at bottom right corner of the video.

I searched for YouTube API for this and couldn't find any clue. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the logo goes, your best bet would probably be to extend the [YouTubePlayerView](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerView) and add the logo on top of the video.

For displaying the image, I would create a layout that can hold either the video or the image.  You could then use a `FragmentManager` to switch between the image and the video.  Use a `Timer` to display the image for 2 seconds and then use the `FragmentManager` to switch to the `YouTubePlayerView` (or whatever your extended class is).
Then you will have to extend the `YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener` to work with your new view.  Call the `onStopped()` method of this listener to switch back to the image after the video is done playing.

---

EDIT
What it appears you want to do is some video editing.  This is definitely not something that you will be able to do through the YouTube API, so you have no choice but to do it natively though the app.

First, you will have to convert the image to an mp4 file.  This is no easy task, but this [code](https://github.com/vanevery/Android-MJPEG-Video-Capture-FFMPEG) seems to provide a solution.  Make sure that the video from the image has the same encoding as the original video.  This makes it possible to combine the videos using [MP4Parser](https://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/wiki/AppendTracks) (although I have never actually used this library, it claims to work for this).

Finally, to make the video upload to YouTube with the logo, you will need to decode the video, embed the image onto every frame, and encode again.  Doing this manually would be difficult, so I recommend using something like [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/).  FFmpeg contains a bunch of useful libraries and functions for multimedia data handling like this.  [Here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Android) is a link to an Android wrapper for FFmpeg.  I have used ffmpeg alot in the past and the man page is pretty helpful, but I have not tried it on Android.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But when I upload it to YouTube, it should be reflected in the web also. As per your answer, if we need to play the uploaded videos with in the application, then we can manage as you suggested. But, that is not the case here. Hope I am clear with my question.

Comment: Did you have any luck with any of the libraries from the second half of my post?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The SVN link given for MP4Parser in the link is not working. Some how, I got the parser from http://mp4parser.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/androidtest. But this also not working. I will check with ffmpeg and get back to you.